# Learning Node and issues with mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

i'm learning node and have hit an issue with running a mysql query.  I am certain i am getting connectivity to the mysql db (as when i run the query from the same module as i connect to the DB i am able to print the rows to the console log).  However i get a 500 error when i require the DB connection into my another file and use in the query.  I've spent last few hours on stack overflow and still stuck.  Its definitely not the function as if i just return text it works fine so its definitely something around the way i am utilising the db connection.  The DB connection file is below:

```js
// initialize database connection
const mysql = require('mysql')
var db;

function connectDatabase() {
    if (!db) {
        db = mysql.createConnection({
          host: process.env.DB_HOST,
          user: process.env.DB_USER,
          password: process.env.DB_PASS,
          database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
        })

        db.connect(function(err){
            if(!err) {
                console.log('Database is connected!')
            } else {
                console.log('Error connecting database!')
            }
        })
    }
    return db
}

module.exports = connectDatabase()
```

The module where the DB connection us used in query below:

```js
const db = require('../db').connectDatabase

exports.getNightlyRatesData = () => {
  //const { rows } = db.query('SELECT * FROM rate', function (err, rows) {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM rate', function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("good");
  })
  return rows
}
```

Comment: `const db = require('../db').connectDatabase` is undefined? From the code it looks like you want `const db = require('../db');`

Comment: When you get a 500 error, you need to check your server log for the detailed error message.

Comment: Both functions dont handle asyncronous behavoir correctly

Comment: "I've spent last few hours on stack overflow and still stuck." I'd rather spent this time learning how to use debugger :) For example with vscode https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging. #learntodebug

Comment: @RolandStarke - this resolved for me and the query will run now.  However i am not really understanding how the connectDatabase function is running.  In my index.js file i have the line require('./db') but by requiring the db module i'm not clear how connectDatabase() function is being called.  Apologies coming to node as a beginner so i'm used to in other languages like php setting constructors in class objects and having to call functions explicitly to utilise the singleton pattern and persist things like a DB connection throughout code.  Any explanation for me appreciated